# Using reflection to dynamically save all the fields in a class? ("<FieldName>","<FieldValue>")

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, properties

I'm trying to avoid hard coding the serialization of a configuration class by using Reflection, and I've ran into a situation where I can't figure anything out. Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a class like so

> ```
> public class Configuration {
>
>    public boolean bool = false;
>    public int integer = 1;
>    public int[] intArray = {0, 1};
>
> }
> ```

I want to use reflection to save the names and values into a
 Properties field.

> ```
> --properties--
> bool=false
> integer=1
> intArray=0,1
> ```

The name part is pretty simple. My issue is getting the value of each field, and especially getting the value of each int[]. Besides the arrays, all values are primitive, so toString() will work just fine.

Can anybody show better examples than Oracle and help me out?

Comment: `new int[]{1,2,3}.toString()` won't work as you expect it to. It will delegate to `Object.toString()`;

Comment: Why don't you use XML or JSON? Both have ready to go serializers and fairly human-readable.

Comment: @llia G I'm not actually using a Propteries object to save the results to a file. I'm working on a pretty complicated way of saving the setting of gui's, and initiating them from a Configuration file. I'm going to use a properties file to set the value of the JComponent on the initiation of the gui. I used the Component.setName(String) method to the name of the corrisponding value in the Configuration file.

Comment: Since you cannot know the exact field type at runtime you'll have to make a case for every primitive and call to the corresponding get<type> method on the Field class using the Reflection classes.

Comment: @ggreiner is there anyway to parse the array into maybe an Object[]?

Comment: @Roberto Linares It wont be that big of a deal. I'm on using int, bool, int[]

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use an array ? If not, you could represent your object as a list and that will print a list representation of your integers.

```
public boolean bool = false;
public int integer = 1;
public int[] intArray = {0, 1}; // <-- This prints array's memory address
public List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 2 , 3); // <-- This prints [1,2,3]

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Config c = new Config();
     for ( Field f : c.getClass().getDeclaredFields() ) {
           System.out.println(f.get(c));
     }

 }
```

Alternatively, you could just do that at runtime.

```
if ( "int[]".equals(f.getType().getSimpleName() ) ) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.utils.Arrays.toString(int[] a) method. 
to get the right array type you can use f.getType().isArray() and f.getType().getComponentType() in Kal's answer.